# pointer to array , assign array

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main() {
    //  int arr[2][2] = { {1,2}, {3,4}};
    int a[] = {1,2};
    int b[] = {3,4};
    int (*ptr)[2];

    // assign ptr to arr
    //ptr = arr;
    ptr = (int (*)[2])malloc (2*sizeof(int));
    ptr = &a;
    (ptr+1) = b;  // error here
     printf("%3d %3d", ptr[0][1], ptr[1][1]) ;
 }
```

I want (ptr+1) assgin one array , please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` is a pointer to an int array(`int[2]`), but you malloc the wrong size, and then, leaking the memory by assigning to the same variable, thus overriding the `malloc` memory address. I assume you want to do that:

```
int (**ptr)[2];
ptr = malloc (2*sizeof(int(*)[2]));
ptr[0] = &a;
ptr[1] = &b;
```

Comment: ptr is a pointer to an int array (int [2]) equivalent two-dimensional array (ptr = arr ). Beause, I think (ptr+1) will pointer to an array. Please explain help me , error here . Thanks.

Comment: `pointer != array` the allocation you did in `malloc` was an allocation to create a 2-ints array, not 2 2-ints arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = {1,2};
    int b[] = {3,4};
    int **ptr;

    ptr = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);

    ptr[0] = a;
    ptr[1] = b;
    printf("%3d %3d\n", ptr[0][1], ptr[1][1]);
    free(ptr);
 }
```

a and b already are pointers (to integers), so ptr is a pointer to a pointer (**).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2};
    int b[] = {3,4};
    int *ptr[2] = { a, b };

    printf("%3d %3d", ptr[0][1], ptr[1][1]) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can malloc like this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int a[] = {1,2};
    int b[] = {3,4};
    int *ptr[2];    //same as ptr[2][??]

    ptr[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);  //malloc ptr[0] >> 2 * sizeof int
    ptr[1] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 5);  //malloc ptr[1] >> 5 * sizeof int

    /* so we get ptr[0][2] and ptr[1][5]*/

    /* SET VALUE */
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    ptr[0][i] = i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    ptr[1][i] = i;


    /* PRINT VALUE */
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("ptr[0][%03d] = %03d\n", i, ptr[0][i]);

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("ptr[1][%03d] = %03d\n", i, ptr[1][i]);


    /* FREE POINTER */
    free(ptr[0]);
    free(ptr[1]);

    return 0;
}
```